# Can't get to work a simple 301 Redirect in Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Normally this should be easy but it doesn't seems to work.

I'm migrating an old website to a wordpress and so I need to do all the redirections in the htaccess file.

What I'm trying to achieve :

/XXX (and anything after it) redirects to /YYY/XXX

My code :

```
RewriteRule ^XXX(.*)$ /YYY/XXXX [L,R=301]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^XXX(.*)$ /YYY/XXXX [L,R=301]` should redirect `/XXX` to `/YYY/XXX` . What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @starkeen well like I said this doesn't work. It just doesn't redirect.

Comment: so you are typing `/XXX` into your browser but nothing is happening?  What url do you see in your browser location bar ?

Comment: @starkeen I get a 404. because on the new website /XXX doesn't exist. If I try /XXX/whateverblabla it stays the same too.

RedirectPermanent /XXX /YYY/XXX works though. But then it doesn't work when I try /XXX/whateverblabla because then I get a 404 and /YYY/XXX/whateverblabla.